# How to Group By in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this query to get the Sum of SaleAmount for each type (SOType) of Sale Invoices.
I am getting the result but the result is not grouped by SOType. Have tried to use Group by Outside the query after where condition but getting an error as

> "Column 'SaleInvoices.InvoiceID' is invalid because it is not
>   contained in either aggregate or group by function".

```
DECLARE @fromDate Datetime = '2019/05/23'
DECLARE @toDate Datetime = '2019/10/25'
DECLARE @isKpi int = '1'

SELECT (                      
  (Select Sum((Isnull(I.Quantity,0)*Isnull(I.SalePrice,0))+((Isnull(I.Quantity,0)*Isnull(I.SalePrice,0) - I.Discount) *(I.TAX/100))) 
  from ItemsSold as I 
  where I.InvoiceId= S.InvoiceID and I.InvoiceType='Sale Invoice'
  ) -
  (Select isnull(Sum((Isnull(I.Quantity,0)*Isnull(I.SalePrice,0))+((Isnull(I.Quantity,0)*Isnull(I.SalePrice,0) - I.Discount)*(I.TAX/100))),0)
  from ItemsSold as I 
  where I.InvoiceId= S.InvoiceID and I.InvoiceType='Sale Return'

  )) as Total

  ,S.SOType as SOType 

  FROM SaleInvoices AS S

  where S.OrderDate>=Convert(VARCHAR,@fromDate,111) and S.OrderDate<=Convert(varchar,@toDate,111)
```

[image]

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation.  The logic should look something like this:

```
select s.SOType,                      
       sum(case when i.invoicetype = 'Sale Invoice'
                then (I.Quantity * I.SalePrice) * (1 - i.discount) * i.tax / 100.0 
                when i.invoicetype = 'Sale Return'
                then - (I.Quantity * I.SalePrice) * (1 - i.discount) * i.tax / 100.0
            end) as Total
from SaleInvoices s join
     ItemsSold i
     on i.InvoiceId= s.InvoiceID 
where s.OrderDate >= @fromDate and 
      s.OrderDate <= @toDate
group by s.SOType ;
```

I'm not sure I got the arithmetic correct.

Notes:

- The `group by` clause defines the rows being returned by the query.  If you want one row per `SOType` then you want to `GROUP BY SOType`.
- Use date comparisons and functions for dates.  It is absurd to convert a date to a string to compare to a date.
- You probably don't need `COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()` to handle `NULL` values.  These are generally ignored by aggregation functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir ! it helped with minor changes (Tax and Discount implementation is wrong) and also IsNull is required else it shows just 0. But you made it simple and i understand it now . Stay always blessed :)

Comment: also `i.InvoiceType = Sale` at the end is not required :)